# Qlik Sense .dll building error (with Unity)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, qliksense

I have been having a problem with building a project within the Unity engine. I am trying to make a connection between Qlik Sense and therefore need some dll's (that I assume is the root of my problem).
When Building, I get two errors in the console:

> ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic is referenced by
>   Qlik.Sense.Communication ('Assets/bin/Qlik.Sense.Communication.dll').
>   But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse
>   (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]
>   alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths,
>   System.String[] foldersToSearch,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[TKey,TValue] cache,
>   UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:142)
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse
>   (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
>   alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths,
>   System.String[] foldersToSearch,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[TKey,TValue] cache,
>   UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:148)
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[]
>   paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
>   target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:179)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

and directly after

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with
>   errors.   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
>   [0x00050] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

The version of Unity that I use is 2017.1.0f3, and should be compatible with 4.6 .NET (which I have also set in edit -> project settings -> player, so that is not the problem).

I can paste some code if you think it is necessesary, but i think the problems lie within either Visual Studio or Unity.

Any tips are appreciated!
/Erik

Comment: `ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic is referenced by Qlik.Sense.Communication ('Assets/bin/Qlik.Sense.Communication.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.` So have you referenced `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`?

Comment: @Equalsk Well, shit. That worked! I'm pretty new to dll's and didn't think I needed to include the .dll in the actual project, and that the reference inside Visual Studio was enough.
Lesson learned. Thank you!

Comment: No problem!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Equalsk hinted at:
Add the .dll into the bin-folder inside your Unity project.